# Flask-WTForms change a submitted datefield value

Tags: python, flask-wtforms

I use WTForms via the flask-WTF extention. I want to change the value of a datefield after it is submitted. 
Here is an example:

```
class ExampleForm1(Form):
    date1 = DateField('Date', description = 'Select date..')
    submit_button = SubmitField('OK')

@app.route("/exampleform1", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def example1():
    form = ExampleForm1()
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
            print str(form.date1)
            print form.date1.data

            form.date1.process_data(date(2000, 01, 01))
            print str(form.date1)
            print form.date1.data
            return render_template('example1.html', form=form)

    form.date1.process_data(date.today())
    return render_template('example1.html', form=form)
```

Here is the output:

```
<input id="date1" name="date1" type="date" value="2015-03-15">
2015-03-15
<input id="date1" name="date1" type="date" value="2015-03-15"> <-- This isn't updated
2000-01-01 <-- this is updated
```

The webpage still displays 2015-03-15 and not 2000-01-01. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

So, yeah... two years later and I've been hit by this issue more than once as well.  And finally, frustratingly gotten to the bottom of it (I don't know why this isn't better known / this question hasn't already been answered), but if you look at the source of (`DateTimeField`, which `DateField` inherits from),

https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/master/wtforms/fields/core.py#L732

```
def _value(self):
    if self.raw_data:
        return ' '.join(self.raw_data)
    else:
        return self.data and self.data.strftime(self.format) or ''
```

If `raw_data` is set, it returns that.

So, you *could* set `raw_data` to None, and that would then return this as the value for the  field, following the breadcrumb trail,

https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/master/wtforms/fields/core.py#L141

https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/master/wtforms/meta.py#L47

https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/master/wtforms/widgets/core.py#L177

```
def __call__(self, field, **kwargs):
    kwargs.setdefault('id', field.id)
    kwargs.setdefault('type', self.input_type)
    if 'value' not in kwargs:
        kwargs['value'] = field._value()
    return HTMLString('<input %s>' % self.html_params(name=field.name, **kwargs))
```

But better would be to "properly" process it,

https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/master/wtforms/fields/core.py#L256

```
    ...
    if formdata is not None:
        if self.name in formdata:
              self.raw_data = formdata.getlist(self.name)
    ...
```

Process is expecting an `ImmutableMultiDict`, so for your situation, instead of,

```
form.date1.process_data(date(2000, 01, 01))
```

You do a "full" process, passing in a properly formed `ImmutableMultiDict`,

```
form.date1.process(ImmutableMultiDict(
  [('date1', date(2000, 01, 01).strftime(form.date1.format))]))
```

It expects its fields to be strings, and for a `DateField`, to be in the proper format of the field, so that's why I'm doing a `strftime` on it, and using its own format, so we're "kinda" cheating.

To help this process, as I use it in a few different places, I use this helper function,

```
def full_field_process(field, val):
    field.process(ImmutableMultiDict([(field.short_name, val)]))
```

which in your situation, would be called like,

```
full_field_process(
    form.date1,
    date(2000, 01, 01).strftime(form.date1.format))
```

Frustrating that it isn't easier, and you don't have a flag, or something to do a raw process, when you do a regular process, but c'est la vie.  That's how you do it, so now this,

```
<input id="date1" name="date1" type="date" value="2015-03-15">
2015-03-15
<input id="date1" name="date1" type="date" value="2000-01-01">
2000-01-01
```

Is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck on this, so I hope this helps someone in the future... @seaders said

> So, you could set raw_data to None, and that would then return this as the value for the field, following the breadcrumb trail,

but that didn't work for me. What worked is setting raw_data to a list containing a date string. So if you wanted to set the form date field to "2020-12-01", you would do

```
form.target_data.raw_data = ["2020-12-01"]
```

as well as doing

```
form.target_data.process_data(date(2020, 12, 01))
```

I hope they fix this sometime.